# "E" and "I" symbols in istanbul HTML reports

Tags: istanbul

what do the "I" and "E" symbols with the black backgrounds signify in the HTML reports generated by the istanbul JS code coverage tool?

[image]

Answer (score 42):

These symbols are in front of if-else statements.

As you can see in the image you have attached, '**E**' is in front of an if-else statement in which the '**E**lse' block is not covered and '**I**' is in front an if-else statement in which the '**I**f' block is not covered.

Comment: So what does it mean that line 203-205 were hit 10x, if the block is not covered?